# Wordpress Pagination - can't access to second page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I use WP Beginner pagination (without plugin) on my website, but I can't access to second and other pages.

```
<?php

$category = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;

 $custom_query_args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'tutorials','post' ),
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'cat' => $cat_id,
 );

// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Instantiate custom query
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

// Pagination fix
$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

// Output custom query loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
                        $custom_query->the_post();

            echo '<article class="other-post col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">';
            echo '<div class="back-color">';
            echo '<h3>';
            echo the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'post-image' ));
            echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. get_the_title() .'">';
            echo '<span><b>'. get_the_title() .'</b></span>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</h3>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</article>';

        endwhile;
endif;

// Reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// Custom query loop pagination
wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav();


// Reset main query object
$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Here is code from function.php, but I think it isn't the problem.
http://virtual-wizard.eu/function.txt

Comment: I see you're using code from wpbeginner.. I tested my own code on custom theme. I've made a tutorial out of it.  (TESTED)
https://prabinparajuli.com.np/add-custom-pagination-in-wordpress/

Comment: The same error with your solution too.

Comment: Did you flush your permalink? I think 404 error is because your permalink isn't flushed. 
Go to Permalink and just save it. You'll see it working :)

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing the `paged` parameter in your query args.

I would also replace the page query, so instead of this:

```
// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

You have this:

```
// Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $paged = 1;
}
```

And then change your query to this:

```
$custom_query_args = array(
   'post_type' => array( 'tutorials','post' ),
   'posts_per_page' => 2,
   'cat' => $cat_id,
   'paged' => $paged,
);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: No, there is still the same problem. 404 Page not found when I click on page 2.

Comment: Okay, well without being able to dive into your code, I would recommend looking at how your permalinks are structured. That can often be an issue, if you’re getting a 404 in your pagination. Are you familiar with permalinks in WordPress? If not, here is some [useful information from Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead. Make sure to read through as they are explaining how to implement this function into your WP website.

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

Function is setup inside of a functions.php and on the specific page when you want to display pagination just call the function like pagination();

Before calling out pagination check also the CSS part and structure of the pagination to get the desired effect.

Srecno!